# Kdevelop and Kate kio problem - won't save sftp:// files (nor fish://)

Tags: ssh, kde, sftp, kate, kdevelop

I have KUbuntu 19.10, and I have problems with opening and saving files from my remote server using both sftp and fish protocols.

Whenever I try to open file from a remote location, it says: "Malformed URL ." both in KDevelop and Kate, and when I try to save it in Kdevelop it simply doesn't save the file, it simply ignores it, like haven't clicked "Save".

I've tried upgrading KDE to the latest one using Ubuntu Backports to 5.18.3, but the problem got even worse, now Kdevelop won't even save local files.

kio-extras and kio-extras-data is installed.

```
KDE Plasma version is: 5.18.3
KDE Frameworks version is: 5.67.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4
Kernerl version: 5.3-0-51-generic
OS Type: 64bit.
CPU: Ryzen 7 3700X
Motherboard: ASUS TUF GAMING X570-PLUS (WI-FI)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest version 20.04 seems to have done the trick, I've submitted the bug to the bugs.kde.org and according to the KDE guys, they've recently done several bug fixes which have gone to the 20.04 version, but are not yet present in the backports.

Small note, I've upgraded to 20.04 using

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

which upgrades to the development version, since the normal version was not available to upgrade yet at the time of the writing of this answer